# Get current/active screen of JVx application

Tags: java, jvx

I have a JVx application with lots of screens (> 150) and want to create an admin screen which takes care of the current/active screen. The admin screen is a modal screen and implemented as popup.

Is it possible to get the current/active screen for the application?

I tried to iterate all components and check by class, but this is not technology independent because desktop has frames, web has panels and mobile has a wrapper panel.

Is there an API for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an API for that.

Use the application and call

```
getActiveControllable()
```

to get the active screen.

But be careful, can be `null`.

I found a [blog post](https://blog.sibvisions.com/2014/03/05/jvx-new-controllercontrollable-old-school-record-navigation/) about the API and above call works for me.